# Is there a way of saving an HTML page to a file which is sent from an express server?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, save

I'm building a web app in which the HTML code is indirectly editable by the user. Elements are added according to user input. For instance, input boxes can be directly inserted by the user pressing 'enter', however the web page from my server is a static page. I want the user to be able to click a 'save' button, and the whole page on the now-edited client side is saved to the original file which was sent so their edits are saved for next time they visit my site.

Saving the file is not allowed to be done on the clients local disk.

How can I go about doing this?

```
let save =document.querySelector('btnSave');

save.addEventListener('onclick',saveFile);

function saveFile(e){
...
}
```

Comment: Read about the [`content-disposition` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) on the response you send from the server.  This information is helpful when you want a response from your server coming back to the browser to tell the browser to offer the user an option to save this as a file on their local disk.  From the title of your question, this is what I thought you were going to ask, but the rest of the question just leaves me totally confused about what you're really trying to do as the client side code you show has nothing to do with this.

Comment: File saving has to be done server-side so I can't save to a local disk unfortunately. I've revised the question

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do.  I'll opt out as far too confused by the question to know how to help.